# How to keep certain part of my app common in entire application

Tags: android, footer

I want to have a list of certain important things(which I am fetching from server every 15 seconds) which I want to have constant(or common) in my entire application. So when I move to next activity by Intents(or any other methods) I should have the list all the time. Is it possible in android ??

I want different solutions which requires as less work as possible.
Please Help..

EDIT: I think I havent made myself clear. I am not worried about how to store data..I am asking as to how can I achieve a view in which only half of the screen changes(as we move from activity to activity) while other half remains constant(doesnt move). Can it be possible ??

Answer (score 1):

Your application class instance is always accesible from any activity.

All you need to do is create the application class like this:

```
public class YourApp extends Application {
....
}
```

And then modify the following line in your app AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<application
    android:name="your.package.YourApp"
```

Now you can access this class everywhere:

```
YourApp appInstance = (YourApp)getApplication();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the PreferencesManager like the one below, create your POJO to access the PreferencesManager.

```
// TODO: Auto-generated Javadoc
/**
 * The Class PreferenceManager.
 */
public class PreferenceManager {

    /** The Constant TAG. */
    private static final String TAG = PreferenceManager.class.getSimpleName();

    /** The default shared preferences. */
    private static SharedPreferences defaultSharedPreferences = null;

    /**
     * Inits the.
     *
     * @param context the context
     */
    public static final void init(Context context){
        defaultSharedPreferences = android.preference.PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        log("Initialize PreferenceManager!");
        UserSettings.init(context);
    }

    /**
     * Save.
     *
     * @param name the name
     * @param value the value
     */
    static final void save(String name,String value){
        if( value != null ){
            Editor edit = defaultSharedPreferences.edit();
            edit.remove(name);
            edit.putString(name, value);
            edit.commit();
        }else{
            Editor edit = defaultSharedPreferences.edit();
            edit.remove(name);
            edit.commit();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Gets the.
     *
     * @param name the name
     * @param defaultValue the default value
     * @return the string
     */
    public static final String get(String name,String defaultValue){
        return defaultSharedPreferences.getString(name, defaultValue);
    }

    /**
     * Save state.
     *
     * @param name the name
     * @param state the state
     */
    public static final void saveState(String name,Bundle state){
        if( state != null && state.size() > 0 ){
            Parcel parcel = Parcel.obtain();
            parcel.writeBundle(state);
            String encodeToString = Base64.encodeToString(parcel.marshall(), Base64.DEFAULT);
            PreferenceManager.save(name, encodeToString);
        }else{
            PreferenceManager.save(name, null);
        }
        log("Saved state "+name);
    }

    /**
     * Gets the state.
     *
     * @param name the name
     * @return the state
     */
    public static final Bundle getState(String name){
        log("Get state "+name);
        String encryptedValue = "";
        try {
            encryptedValue = PreferenceManager.get(name, "");
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            return new Bundle();
        }
        if( "".equals(encryptedValue) ){
            return new Bundle();
        }else{
            byte[] decode = Base64.decode(encryptedValue, Base64.DEFAULT);
            Parcel parcel = Parcel.obtain();
            parcel.unmarshall(decode, 0, decode.length);
            parcel.setDataPosition(0);
            return parcel.readBundle();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Log.
     *
     * @param msg the msg
     */
    private static final void log(String msg){
        Log.d(TAG, msg);
    }

}



/**
 * The Class Settings.
 */
public class UserSettings {

    /** The settings bundle. */
    private final Bundle settingsBundle = new Bundle(1);

        /**
     * Save.
     */
    public final void save() {
        PreferenceManager.saveState(SETTINGS_STATE_NAME, settingsBundle);
    }

    /**
     * Restore.
     */
    final public void restore() {
        settingsBundle.clear();
        Bundle state = PreferenceManager.getState(SETTINGS_STATE_NAME);
        if (state.size() == 0) {
            settingsBundle.putAll(getDefaultValuesSettings());
        } else {
            settingsBundle.putAll(state);
        }
    }

    final void reset() {
        settingsBundle.clear();
    }


    /**
     * Gets the settings.
     *
     * @return the settings
     */
    public static UserSettings getSettings() {
        return settings;
    }

    /**
     * Inits the.
     *
     * @param ctx the ctx
     */
    public static final void init(Context ctx) {
        settings.restore();
        setDeviceUniqueId(ctx, settings);
    }

}
```

Example usage:

```
public class YourApplication extends Application {
....
    onCreate(){
    ....
    PreferenceManager.init(getBaseContext());
    }                                   
}

Where you need your data to be stored and retrieved use the methods like below.
UserSettings.getSettings().setUser(responseVal);
UserSettings.getSettings().save();

String response = UserSettings.getSettings().getUser();
```

Comment: Well in that case you need not cache the data. you can use an IntentService to download the data. refer to this project https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful. For more info on IntentService check this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html

Comment: @LalithB-I am not interested about data..I am interested about view !!

Comment: Be clear as what you want. if you are polling every 15 sec you need to have a SheduledIntent service which is well implemented by cwac. If you want the view not to refresh every 15 sec write your code in onCreate() and dont refreshview.

Comment: I told u that I am aware as how to fetch the data...I am only interested in how to make the lower half of my app static across whole app...

Comment: you can create a fragment on the top part of the screen and push/pop the fragment the way you want, the bottom half of the view can be instantiated and updated from your Activity.

Answer (score 0):

If it's large amount of data, you can store your data using Shared Preferences or SQLite DB. If it is less amount of data then you can go for static variables. If you use static variables, when any crash occurs in the app that data may lost. Hence static variables usage is less preferable.

Comment: @Kameswari- I am fetching data every 15 sec from server...so I am not much worried about data...but it shouldn't fetch data every time new activity is fetched !

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of ways to do this :

1. You can store them and put in your application's SQLite database (Data is Persistent till you delete the application or delete through your application code )
   See the SQLite usage [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html)
2. You use Cache them in the phone memory till the time your app runs.
   See Cache usage here [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LruCache.html)

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use [`SQLite`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary.html) database to store this data and then create singleton helper to read it.
2. Or you can use save your data in `XML` or `JSON` format as files, then parse them to read.
3. Or you can create class-container for one entity of your data, make it serializable and store in [`SharedPreferences`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) as `ArrayList<YourDataContainer>`